# (FB Instant games) How I can get/set screen resolution?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-games

How can I get/set screen resolution for instant games in mobile facebook app or mesenger? I tried getting that by "window.screen.width" and "window.innerWidth", it returned me 360 pixels (but i have 980 in Chrome browser). I haven’t used any meta tags which can limit the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

You need to multiply these by `window.devicePixelRatio`.

So:

```
PixelW = window.innerWidth *  window.devicePixelRatio;
PixelH = window.innerHeight *  window.devicePixelRatio;
```